# UV map shows squares instead of rectangle

Tags: uv, edit-mode, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to UV export a very simple rectangle so that I can import it in Photoshop to paint my rectangle. I need to do this because my game engine requires both the naked model file and texture file.

The problem is that whenever I try to unwrap the rectangle I get the unwrapped image on the left .. which shows the faces as squares instead of rectangles. This makes painting REALLY hard since I'm painting in a square (1:1 ratio) which gets translated to a rectangle.

My question is: How do I unwrap my rectangular model in a way that the UV map shows the result in rectangles instead of squares?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to BSE,

Have you applied the scale of the object?

In object mode, please press CTRL+A and select Scale. Then retry the UV unwrap.

Comment: You are a legend. This did the trick, I've spent so many hours and the solution was that straight forward. 

Thank you so much!